# NsMutable Array problem

Tags: ios4, sdk, nsmutablearray

when i remove object from nsmutable array it shows exception but some time it works

```
[Array removeObjectAtIndex:row];
```

i have use this code

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Answer (score 1):

Array is type of `NSarray` ... it is object of `NSArray` it should be object of `NSMutableArray` and not `NSArray`

Comment: i did not use object  of nsArray am just amazed why it is give this exception some times it works fine